# Cannot Install Android SDK

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

I know there are any questions on SO about installing the Android SDK. I have been reading them for 2 days. No matter what I do, I get the following:

> ```
> Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
> Fetched Add-ons List successfully
> Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
> Done loading packages.
> Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
> Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml,
> ```
>
> reason: File not found
>       Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>       Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
>       Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml,
>   reason: File not found
>       Done loading packages.

And only 1 tool shows up:
[image]

What can I do to resolve this?
Running OSX 10.10.2 on MBP

Comment: just an fyi Eclipse development for Android is going away. Switch to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

The issue usually occur when the directory permissions are incorrect. Please check the permissions of your `.android` directory. The sdk update process stores a copy of the repository listing xml in .android/cache, which will apparently fail silently if the permissions are incorrect.

If this failed then try this.

You can just fix it by running eclipse as an administrator: In the Terminal, type `"sudo <your installation folder>/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse"`

for Windows user, please run **SDK Manager** as an Administrator.

If that doesn't work then you can always install it manually, please follow one of these links,

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/6588/how-to-install-android-sdk-without-internet-connection/
http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html

Comment: This happened to me on Mac OS X, see this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76268

Answer (score 0):

Did you downloaded the ADT plugin?

[ADT Plugin - 23.0.4](https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.4.zip)

> Start Eclipse, then select **Help > Install New Software**.

Click Add, in the **top-right corner**.

In the Add Repository dialog, click **Archive**.

Select the downloaded **ADT-23.0.4.zip** file and click **OK**.

Enter "**ADT Plugin**" for the name and click OK.

In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to **Developer Tools** and click **Next**.

In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click **Next**.

Read and accept the license agreements, then click **Finish**.

After that Go to **`Preferences>Android`** and **Browse** for the **SDK Location**.